# Sibling nodes in ElementTree in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, nodes

I am looking at a piece of XML that I want to add a node in.

```
<profile>
    <dog>1</dog>
        <halfdog>0</halfdog>
    <cat>545</cat>
        <lions>0</lions>
    <bird>23</bird>
        <dino>0</dino>
        <pineapples>2</pineapples>
    <people>0</people>
</profile>
```

With the above XML, I'm able to insert XML nodes into it. However, I'm not able to insert it at exact locations.

Is there a way to find if I am next to a certain node, whether it be before or after. Say if I wanted to add `<snail>2</snail>` between the `<dino>0</dino>` and `<pineapples>2</pineapples>` nodes.

Using `ElementTree` how can I find what node is next to me? I'm asking about `ElementTree` or any standard Python library. Unfortunately, `lxml` is out of the question for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe its not doable using ElementTree, but you can do it using the standard [python minidom](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html):

```
# create snail element
snail = dom.createElement('snail')
snail_text = dom.createTextNode('2')
snail.appendChild(snail_text)

# add it in the right place
profile = dom.getElementsByTagName('profile')[0]
pineapples = dom.getElementsByTagName('pineapples')[0]
profile.insertBefore(snail, pineapples)
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><profile>
    <dog>1</dog>
    <halfdog>0</halfdog>
    <cat>545</cat>
    <lions>0</lions>
    <bird>23</bird>
    <dino>0</dino>
    <snail>2</snail><pineapples>2</pineapples>
    <people>0</people>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the parent element and the element to insert before, you can use the following method with ElementTree:

```
index = parentElem.getchildren().index(elemToInsertBefore)
parent.insert(index, newElement)
```

Comment: Note if using Python 3.2 or above: `getchildren()` is deprecated and can be replaced with `list(elem)` [(see the Python 3 documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getchildren).
The first line would then instead become
`index = list(parentElem).index(elemToInsertBefore)`